# Can someone translate this text?

Tags: translation, character-identification

This is an old silver stuff, what is the text?

Can you help me?

[image]

This is the back of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is basically "the Avenue(巷） of Auspicious（吉祥）"

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the back of it:`丁財`

be blessed with many male children and great wealth

```
the third 家？
```

Comment: Thank you very much!